# How can I undo userland access to a Windows system directory?

Tags: windows-10, security, permissions

While trying to [force a font cache rebuild](https://winaero.com/rebuild-font-cache-windows-10/), I navigated to %WinDir%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService and got a dialog like this one:

> You don't currently have permission to access this folder.
> Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder.

I clicked "Continue" before realizing that this *permanently* grants my user account access to what ought to be an Administrator-only directory, with all of the security holes that causes.

**How can I undo userland 'permanently get access to this folder', and restore this folder to its default permissions?**

(I've already done what I needed to do in that directory properly using an admin command prompt; I just need to undo my security permissions mistake.)

[image]

Comment: To reset permissions for a folder: icacls "full path to the folder" /reset . To reset permissions for a folder, its files, and subfolders, run the command icacls "full path to the folder" /reset /t /c /l       https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls

Comment: @John I tried that, but when I navigate to that folder in Explorer, it doesn't display that dialog for me again. So icacls /reset has evidently *not* reverted the folder back its default UAC status.

Comment: Just as a thought, try restarting the computer after you make this change.

Comment: If the common solution of resetting the permissions doesn’t work, you won’t like the solution, that probably involves reinstalling Windows entirely.  I would of course run SFC and DISM before reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Actually, it seems icacls /t /c /l was actively harmful, as now I can get at the *sub*directories of LocalServices without getting the UAC dialog. Before icacls, I would still get the popup for LocalServices/AppData, even though it didn't show for LocalServices.

Comment: That should not be a harmful command. Perhaps the issues with your system led Ramhound to the idea of reinstalling Windows. If you are the only user, or the only Administrative user, I would let it be and see if the next feature update fixes it. I routinely allow myself access to windows\temp and I must re-allow access after a feature upgrade.